# USort Multi Index Array - Doesn't Return Correctly

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, usort

I'm having trouble with PHPs [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function. I currently have a multi-indexed array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => c
                    [more_fields] => '...'
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => a
                    [more_fields] => '...'
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [title] => b
                    [more_fields] => '...'
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [title] => xz
                    [more_fields] => '...'
                )

        )
)
```

I'm trying to loop through the array and sort each index by the `title` index. Here's the code without any of my test inputs:

```
foreach( $my_arr as $arr ) {
    if( count( $arr ) > 1 ) {
        usort( $arr, function( $a, $b ) {
            return strcasecmp( $a['title'], $b['title'] );
        } );
    }
}
```

Now I would expect that to work, and I know I'm hitting the right indexes, if I echo out `$a['title']` and `$b['title']` before I return I get data that looks like:

```
a _ c | xz _ a | b _ a | c _ a | b _ c | xz _ b | c _ b | xz _ c
```

That's fine and dandy, but once the `foreach` is finished, my array is unchanged. It looks like, looking at the PHP docs that `usort()` is passing the array by reference and returning booleans on completion. What am I missing in my `usort()` that keeps leaving my array unchanged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foreach` works on a copy of the array.  To modify the actual array you need to reference the value (notice the `&`):

```
foreach( $my_arr as &$arr ) {
```

Or you should be able to use the key and the actual array `$my_arr[$key]`:

```
foreach( $my_arr as $key => $arr ) {
    if( count( $arr ) > 1 ) {
        usort( $my_arr[$key], function( $a, $b ) {
            return strcasecmp( $a['title'], $b['title'] );
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: I should've known how the foreach works but I guess my brain kept glossing over it and blaming usort. Thanks for pointing that out / your help! will accept when allowed to.